# how to download file in fixtures/Downloads folder cypress

Tags: cypress

This will download in in cypress\downloads folder which i not want to download , i need to change the download location in fixtures

cy.readFile("cypress\downloads" + fileName + ".csv").should("exist");

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of downloads in cypress.json like this:

```
{
  "viewportHeight": 880,
  "viewportWidth": 1280,
  "downloadsFolder": "yourPathHere"
}
```

In the code below, the property "downloadsFolder" is responsible to change the location of downloads. More information [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files).